# How do i test if a fragment has been replaced by another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso

I am trying to test if my fragment changes over to another fragment when I press the send button. My two fragments are in an activity and replace the other when the send button is pressed.

Comment: Put a TexVview with "1" in the first, and a "2" in the second? Or do I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 1):

> First you need to start activity. Then add first fragment button click and find second fragment any view is displayed or not.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeFragmentTest {
    @Test
    fun testNewsFragment() {

        // launch desired activity
        val firstActivity: ActivityTestRule<SampleActivity> = ActivityTestRule(SampleActivity::class.java)
        firstActivity.launchActivity(Intent())

        // first fragment button id here instead of "R.id.news_dest"
        onView(withId(R.id.news_dest)).perform(click())
        // second fragment is view id
        onView(withId(R.id.txtViewSecond)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```